# Is there an algorithm to compress a version 4 GUID to less than 16 bytes?

Tags: guid

I reverse engineered the Windows UuidCreate() method assembly and am guessing it's the same algorithm that MS uses for SQL Server. Anyhow, it is a recursive algorithm which self-modifies a 256 byte array as it uses that same 256 byte array to generate the 16 GUID bytes. There are actually 8 such 256 byte arrays that they round robin through. After 8 GUIDs generated they cycle back to the first. They basically just sum up the bytes, adding in one more byte at a time to the sum, doing a mod base 256 on the sum as they go and then swapping current byte with the byte value at that offset in that array, then summing up those 2 values jut swapped to then index back into that array to grab the next GUID byte. I've been thinking about this a few months now off and on and can't figure out away to compress it. Anyone know of any group theory behind any such algorithm which might be able to compress such a version 4 GUID?

Comment: [Version 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) is supposed to be 122 bits of pseudo-random data plus 4 bits for the version and 2 reserved bits. You could "compress" it by removing the 6 non-random bits, but it's a feature of (properly generated) pseudo-random data that it doesn't compress well.

Comment: Of course, if you knew the seed from which the bits were generated, and could implement the algorithm to generate them, you could just store the seed.

Comment: thanks yep however the seed is the 8 256-byte arrays. And then to try to generate say the one millionth GUID from that would require generating all one million GUIDs up to that...unless I can find a way to jump to the Nth GUID or better yet the exact one millionth GUID. But I'm afraid your answer is correct and there just is no known way to do that.